# how to create an object of the same class in c#?

Tags: c#, activator, createinstance

I need an instance of the same class as another object, but I don't know the exact type. I have the following code.

```
abstract public class Row{
     .
     .
     .
}

public class User : Row{
    .
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
.
User test = new User();
Open(test);
.
.
.

private Row backup;

public static void Open(Row row){
    .
    .
    .
    db.backup = (Row) Activator.CreateInstance(row.GetType());
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But when I run the program it generates NullReferenceException and I don't understand why... I tested it on the debugger and "row" is not null, everything seems right.

I googled it but no luck... however I read comments of people complaining about Activator.CreateInstance being too slow... is that true? what the best way to do this job?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile - you are accessing an instance member (`backup`) from a static method (`Open`).  What is the _exact_ exception you get (and on what line)

Comment: I have similar code working with no problems. Can you provide more info from the exception? Stacktrace and which line you posted throws it would be good.

Comment: What do you plan to do once you create a `User` object?

Comment: @DStanley: Sorry it actually says: db.backup, so it does compile

Comment: @evanmcdonnal: there is no more information, just the name of the source file and the line in which the exception occurs... nothing useful.

Comment: @georgeb then post your _actual_ code (or at least enough to replicate the problem)

Comment: @georgeb no, it doesn't, because `backup` is still an _instance_ member.

Comment: @georgeb the line number is _very_ useful...

Comment: @georgeb is `db` null?

Comment: @georgeb do you mean that's all you have in your log? All exceptions provide a stack trace...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake... as **D Stanley** correctly pointed out db was null, and that's the reason why the program threw an exception.

Comment: Glad you figure it out - for future reference the debugger is a GREAT tool to weed out such errors.  And it doesn't hurt to add null-check to your code wither.